# objective c - fetch data (core data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have two tables `Photo` and `Photographer`. 
Below is the structure of the tables.

[image: Photo and Photographer]

I'm trying to fetch the name of all `Photographers` who have taken a photo called "Panda".

Here's my code but for some reason it's returning empty.

```
NSArray *matchingPhotographers;
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSEntityDescription *desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photographer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:desc];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photo.name like[c] %@",@"Panda"]];

NSError *error;
matchingPhotographers = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

NSLog(@"Photographers: %@", matchingPhotographers);
```

Am I doing something wrong? The query should definitely return at least 1 photographer.

Thanks

Comment: don't see anything wrong at first glance. you sure it is Panda/panda?

Answer (score 2):

Photo is a collection, so your predicated must be:

```
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY photo.name like[c] %@",@"Panda"]];
```

This predicate finds "Photographers" which have at list one photo (among his photo's collection) with the name like "Panda".

Answer (score 1):

`photo` is a to-many relationship so it's easier to use a subquery predicate to count the photos in the relationship which match your criteria:

```
@"SUBQUERY(photo, $p, $p.name ==[c] %@).@count > 0", @"Photo"
```

Note I'm also not using LIKE so it isn't a regex comparison.

Comment: Aside, `photo` would be better named `photos` so you remember it's a to-many